# The tables and values of the matrix are tripled

Tags: html, vbscript

I can't get the array matrix into one HTML table. For some reason, the tables and values of the matrix are tripled and I don't now why.

Output:

[image]

```vb
Sub writeTable(arrData)
    Dim intCount
    For intCount = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        document.write "<!DOCTYPE html>"
        document.write "<html>"
        document.write "<head>"
        document.write "<style>"
        document.write "table, th, td {"
        document.write "border: 1px solid black;"
        document.write "border-collapse: collapse;"
        document.write "}"
        document.write "</style>"
        document.write "</head>"
        document.write "<body>"
        document.write "<p>Test</p>"
        document.write "<table style='width:50px'>"
        document.write "<tr>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "</tr>"
        document.write "<tr>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "</tr>"
        document.write "<tr>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
        document.write "</tr>"
        document.write "</table>"
        document.write "</body>"
        document.write "</html>"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted creates a complete HTML document with a 3-row table for each row of the array. The following snippet would output a single row:

```vb
document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
```

Repeating that snippet 3 times repeats the row 3 times in the output.

```vb
document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "</tr>"
document.write "<tr>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "</tr>"
document.write "<tr>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, intCount) &"</td>"
document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
```

Only you have a typo in the 2nd statement that causes the first field to be output twice in the first row.

Basically there are 2 ways of fixing the issue:

- Do the loop just for the table rows, not the entire document, and output only a single row in the loop body:

  ```vb
  document.write "<!DOCTYPE html>"
  document.write "<html>"
  ...
  document.write "<p>Test</p>"
  document.write "<table style='width:50px'>"
  For intCount = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
      document.write "<tr>"
      document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
      document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, intCount) &"</td>"
      document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, intCount) &"</td>"
      document.write "</tr>"
  Next
  document.write "</table>"
  document.write "</body>"
  document.write "</html>"
  ```

  This is the recommended way.
- Remove the loop and repeat the statements while incrementing the row index yourself:

  ```vb
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, 0) &"</td>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, 0) &"</td>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, 0) &"</td>"
  document.write "</tr>"
  document.write "<tr>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, 1) &"</td>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, 1) &"</td>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, 1) &"</td>"
  document.write "</tr>"
  document.write "<tr>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(0, 2) &"</td>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(1, 2) &"</td>"
  document.write "<td>"& arrData(2, 2) &"</td>"
  ```

  I don't recommend this approach, because it can't handle a varying number of rows in the array without modifying the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you tell me how to rewrite or update elements in this table or how to rewrite this table without adding new one.